# How did PIE *h₂énti-h₃kʷós get lengthened to Proto-Italic *antīkʷos?

Tags: etymology, proto-indo-european, old-latin

The word *antīquus* has a long vowel in the middle, but the proposition *ante* is short; indeed, if I am not mistaken (it has been a while since I read and wrote about Saturnian), both of its morae are short. If looking at only the word *ante*, we notice that its origin is the same as the first half of *antīquus* (*h₂énti), and the Greek is indeed with a short i (*ἀντί*: /an.tí/), as is also the Sanskrit (अन्ति (ánti)).

The vowel length of Classical Latin *antīquus*, according to what is stated at Wiktionary, goes back to Proto Italic. Now, I don’t know which Greek cognates (if any) there are, but Wiktionary lists अन्तिक (*antika*) for Sanskrit, again with the short vowel. My question thus, restated: How did the *i* in *antīquus* get lengthened, all the way back in its Proto Italic form **antīkʷos*, when this does not seem to appear in its cognates, nor in Latins own *ante*¹?

¹ Though that could be iambic shortening and lowering, I presume.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A laryngeal following a vowel disappears (after colouring that vowel if it's **e*), lengthening that vowel. This process is most prominent within roots, since ablaut means **e* ends up next a laryngeal especially frequently, but it happens across morpheme boundaries within a word as well. In this case, the **h₃* at the start of **-h₃kʷós* lenghtened the **i* at the end of **h₂énti-*, even though they're separate members of the compound word.

The Sanskrit *antika*, though strikingly similar, is not actually cognate: the first part does also reflect **h₂enti-* (the locative singular of **h₂ent-* 'front'), but the second part is the adjective-forming suffix **‑kos*, which does not start with a laryngeal, rather than the zero-grade root **‑h₃kʷ-* 'to see' and the thematic termination **‑os* seen in the Latin.
In a satem language like Sanskrit, the labiovelar **kʷ* ended up falling together with the plain velar **k*, so the only clue that these two words aren't cognate is the length of that vowel, as you spotted—etymology is a subtle science.

Comment: How does this match the Sanskrit development?

Comment: @CannedMan It doesn't. I don't think it's really cognate.

Comment: The suffix in Skt antika- is *ko, as in Greek physikos. It does not lengthen the preceding vowel.

Comment: @fdb Ah, that's what it is. I've added it to the answer.